# Probability question similar to boy-and-girl problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem:**

Each of two balls is painted either black or gold, with probability 1/2 in each case, and these events are independent. The two balls are placed in an urn.

a. Given the known information that at least one of the balls is painted gold, because you know the gold paint has been used, compute the conditional probability that both balls are painted gold (as usual, showing the steps of your reasoning).

b. Somebody hands you one of the balls in the urn, and you see that it’s painted gold. What is the probability that both balls are painted gold, and why?

---

*My current thoughts:*

So I think I got part A correctly. It is a conditional probability about the likelihood that two gold balls would be taken. I did P(2 Gold Balls)= (1/3)

Part B tells me that I'm given one of the balls as Gold. It asks me what are the chances that both balls are painted gold. It can't just be the probability of one of the gold balls (1/2). How do I deal with this question? :( Does any one know what this actually means?!?!

Correct me if I'm wrong but both part A and B are clearly different questions related to probability. Why are they different? I really appreciate your feedback and help.

Comment: Why do you think it "can't just be" 1/2 in part B?

Comment: well for part B I thought one of the balls is given. So are you implying that it should just be a 1/2 probability to get 2 GBs given that one of the GB is given? @HenningMakholm

Comment: I see I got Part A wrong. I think I should have considered the total # of possibilities and hence you get 1/2+1/4. @fgrieu

Comment: No, $\frac12+\frac34$ is definitely wrong -- it is even more than $1$!

Comment: @HenningMakholm so for Part B it is just 1/2 odds for getting the second gold ball? I just thought it looked to simple.

Comment: For B, if everything else fails you, consider all the 8 possible combinations of "which color does each ball get" and "which ball is drawn", exclude the ones where you're handed a black ball, and see which fraction of the remaining cases have both balls be gold.

Comment: I mistyped that time @HenningMakholm it was meant to be 1/2+1/4 sorry about that

Comment: You can only get the following combinations: GB, BG, GG, BB I think. If  know one of it being Gold then I really consider 2 possibilities. GB (3/4) or GG (1/4 chance). @HenningMakholm GB = Gold Black btw

Answer (score 2):

Suppose further that the balls are labeled with a $1$ and a $2$.  This will help us organize our thoughts and create an equiprobable sample space.

For the first part, it is not $Pr(\text{both gold})$, it is $Pr(\text{both gold} \color{red}{| \text{at least one gold}})$.  This is a very important distinction to make.

Our original sample space where we don't care about what order we draw balls in is:  $\{G_1G_2, G_1B_2, B_1G_2, B_1B_2\}$.  Since we are working with the *conditional probability* that at least one of the balls is gold, we can remove $B_1B_2$ from our sample space.  Our conditioned sample space is then $\{G_1G_2,G_1B_2,B_1G_2\}$, each of which are equally likely to occur.  The probability that both are gold given that we know at least one of the balls is gold is then $\frac{1}{3}$.

(*compare this to the boy-girl paradox where we are told at least one of the two children is a girl*)

Our next part we will need to worry about which order the balls are drawn as well, so we put a bit more effort into our sample space.

Here, it is $Pr(\text{both gold}\color{red}{|\text{first ball drawn is gold}})$

Our sample space originally where order matters is $\{G_1G_2,G_2G_1,G_1B_2,B_2G_1,B_1G_2,G_2B_1,B_1B_2,B_2B_1\}$.  Since we are conditioning on the first ball seen being gold, we may remove any and all outcomes from our sample space where the first ball was black.

> This leaves us with the conditioned sample space $\{G_1G_2,G_2G_1,G_1B_2,G_2B_1\}$, again with each equally likely to occur.  Exactly two of the four outcomes here result in both being gold, so the probability is $\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$.

(*compare this to the boy-girl paradox where we are told the eldest child is a girl*)

I will leave the question of why they are different questions to you, but it has something to do with the amount of information we are given.

Comment: About the second part to the question: You calculate the conditional probability of the first ball drawn being gold. But the description says "somebody hands you **one of** the balls". To my mind this is exactly the same scenario as the first part of the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Thanassis So, really, the second part of the question is underspecified, we weren't told how our friend decides which if any ball to give us... but if we were to make the assumption that our friend who pulled the balls will uniformly at random pick one of the two balls to give us then yes this is absolutely a different question than the first.  Equivalently, if our friend always hands us the "*first*" ball that was painted.  Again, in this scenario we have more restrictive information than in the first problem.

Comment: @Thanassis The whole point is, again, that in the first scenario we are told information involving *both* balls... that at least one of them is gold (*first and second, first only, or second only*).  In the second problem we were only told information about the first ball and were not told anything about the second ball.  (*first only or first and second*).  Notably, again, in the second problem we were explicitly told that it is not the case that it was the second ball only which was gold.

Comment: I agree that the second part is underspecified, because we are not told how this other person picks the ball that it hands you. But I do not agree that the most natural assumption is that he pulled it randomly out of the box. To me the most natural assumption is trying not to add any extra info. So all we know is this: one of the two balls is gold, which makes it identical to the first scenario (at least one of the balls is gold). We can of course assume that the scenarios are different through meta-reasoning: expecting to get different scenarios in a test or exercise.

Comment: "*the most natural assumption is trying not to add any extra info*"  Your assumption is adding a *lot* of extra info about how the person acts... namely that the friend will always prefer to show a gold ball if one exists.  Why would he have this preference?  Having no preference is I think a safer assumption than having a very specific preference.  In any case, the working above is explicitly in reference to the problem given the assumption that the friend picks one of the two balls uniformly at random to show.

Comment: Any further discussion about whether this assumption (*which in my experience is the most common assumption made by any self-respecting mathematician*) is the "better" assumption or not is a matter of language or philosophy and not about mathematics.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's a matter of language/philosophy. I wanted to make sure I did not miss something about the maths.